# Commutator of 2 Rotational Matrix in x and z axis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do i find the **commutator of rotational matrix in x and z axis**?

Dx = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&cos\gamma &-sin\gamma \\ 0&sin\gamma &cos\gamma \end{pmatrix}
Dz = \begin{pmatrix}cos\nu &-sin\nu &0\\ sin\nu &cos\nu &0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}

shouldnt the outcome is equal to rotational matrix Dy axis with matrix 
Dy = \begin{pmatrix}cos\theta &0&-sin\theta \\ 0&1&0\\ sin\theta &0&cos\theta \end{pmatrix} ??

here is my working... i dont know how should i continue with the commutation.
besides, **why must the commutation of [Dx, Dz] not equal to 0**?

[image]

Comment: You might find it useful to take a book or cell-phone and try the rotation operations in the two different orders, with 90 degree $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ for each operation:  Do $D_{x}D_{z}$ and compare to $D_{z}D_{x}$.  You should see the book end up in different orientations.  I hope this helps.

Comment: it ending up in the opposite direction, but still... how do i get the commutation of both axis? @@